# String length comparison to an integer seems to return wrong answer

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I'm working on a LeetCode problem ([880. Decoded String at Index](https://leetcode.com/problems/decoded-string-at-index/)) where I need to decode a string following specific rules, and I've come across an issue that I don't understand. I'm using a loop to build the decoded string, but when I compare its length to the value of k, it behaves unexpectedly.

```
class Solution(object):
    def decodeAtIndex(self, s, k):
        newstring = str()
        for i in range(len(s)):
            print(f"checking ({newstring})-({len(newstring)}) is equals to ({k})")
            if len(newstring) == k:
                break
            if s[i].isalpha():
                newstring += s[i]
                continue
            currentstring = newstring
            for j in range(int(s[i])-1):
                newstring += currentstring
        return newstring[k-1]

sol = Solution()

print(sol.decodeAtIndex(s="leet2code3", k=10))
print(sol.decodeAtIndex(s="ha22", k=15))
```

In this example, when I run the function with `sol.decodeAtIndex(s="ha22", k=15)`, I expect it to return a character from the decoded string, but when it enters the `if len(newstring) == k` block when `newstring` has a length of 4 and `k` is 15. So, `4 == 15` evaluates to true, for some reason and that breaks the loop, causing a syntax error because it tries to return

I don't quite understand the problem within the second test, since the first one goes through with no problems and stops generating the newstring when it reaches the correct length.

Missed the fact that running with the provided code also outputs this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>\problem.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(sol.decodeAtIndex(s="ha22", k=15))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<path>\problem.py", line 14, in decodeAtIndex
    return newstring[k-1]
           ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: `So, 4 == 15 evaluates to true, for some reason and that breaks the loop` It does not, your loop just ends. There is no answer for `s="ha22", k=15`.

Comment: That is a very strong assertion you are making. You had better have some evidence to back that up. (And it causes an `IndexError`, not a syntax error)

Comment: `IndexError: string index out of range`

Comment: `s="ha22", k=15` isn't a valid input for this algorithm; the decoded string should only have a length of 8, there *isn't* a character at index 15.  The example input on the site is `s="ha22", k=5`...

Comment: Please post the [verbatim error message](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title and to make a [mre] (in this case that would require the exact expected output beyond just "a character", and it would help to add an explanation of why too). See also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert

Comment: Aside note - you don't have to build entire decoded string, it would be too long. Seek for non brute-force solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, your test doesn't match the assignment: it asks about `s="ha22", k=5`, you have `, k = 15`. That doesn't have an answer, since `s="ha22"` result in the string `"hahahaha"` - and that's only 8 characters long. There is no character at index 15, and you're breaking the given constraint "It is guaranteed that k is less than or equal to the length of the decoded string."

There's another problem in your code that's unrelated:

```
if len(newstring) == k:
    break
```

Since the string can grow longer by steps larger than 1, you probably want to check if `k` is 'greater than or equal` to the length.

You supposed that Python was getting things wrong and evaluating `4 == 15` to `True` - whenever think something like that, you're almost guaranteed to be wrong. A problem that egregious in a language that is the most popular on the planet, would have been found. It's always far more likely that you're missing something important. In this case, a.) an error message that explains the problem, b.) that you got the question wrong, and c.) that your function doesn't exit the loop the way you think it does.

Note that it works either way - in many cases it will just complete the entire decoded string and still return the correct answer.

Here is your code with only 4 changes: the correct question, the 3rd question, a 4th question to demonstrate the problem with your code, and the fix:

```
class Solution(object):
    def decodeAtIndex(self, s, k):
        newstring = str()
        for i in range(len(s)):
            print(f"checking ({newstring})-({len(newstring)}) is equals to ({k})")
            # fixed:
            if len(newstring) >= k:
                break
            if s[i].isalpha():
                newstring += s[i]
                continue
            currentstring = newstring
            for j in range(int(s[i])-1):
                newstring += currentstring
        return newstring[k-1]

sol = Solution()

print(sol.decodeAtIndex(s="leet2code3", k=10))
#this is the correct problem:
print(sol.decodeAtIndex(s="ha22", k=5))
print(sol.decodeAtIndex(s="a2345678999999999999999", k=1))

#an extra problem:
print(sol.decodeAtIndex(s="a22bc2c222222222", k=10))
```

Outputs `o`, `h`, `a` and `a` (with your printed explanations).

Note that if you undo the fix, you get this output for the added problem:

```
checking ()-(0) is equals to (10)
checking (a)-(1) is equals to (10)
checking (aa)-(2) is equals to (10)
checking (aaaa)-(4) is equals to (10)
checking (aaaab)-(5) is equals to (10)
checking (aaaabc)-(6) is equals to (10)
checking (aaaabcaaaabc)-(12) is equals to (10)
checking (aaaabcaaaabcc)-(13) is equals to (10)
checking (aaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabcc)-(26) is equals to (10)
checking (aaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabcc)-(52) is equals to (10)
checking (aaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabcc)-(104) is equals to (10)
checking (aaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabcc)-(208) is equals to (10)
checking (aaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabcc)-(416) is equals to (10)
checking (aaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabcc)-(832) is equals to (10)
checking (aaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabcc)-(1664) is equals to (10)
checking (aaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabccaaaabcaaaabcc)-(3328) is equals to (10)
a
```

Not great, still correct.